# Simple example of approximating a nonlinear system with Volterra series

Tags: power-series, nonlinear-system

I'm trying to understand Volterra series as a means of modelling/approximating nonlinear input-output relations.

I'm having trouble to understand the abstract definitions of kernels/functionals and was looking for a simple example of a nonlinear system and its approximation via Volterra series.

Any help appreciated :)

Comment: What are exactly the definitions you do not understand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try these links:

https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/pdf/analytical_volterra.pdf

Videos (on youtube)
Lecture 14: Volterra Series, Dr. Wim van Drongelen, Modeling and Signal Analysis for Neuroscientists

Comment: Thank you! The links are helpful ;)